# Sunlight-powered device set to change world: will it work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, pressure

Vast areas of desert sand are being shone on upon by the sun. Now that's some ENERGY!

Using this proposed apparatus:

1. Sunlight over large area is concentrated on steam chamber, where water turns into vapor.
2. The high temperatures of the gases in the steam chamber will push on the loose piston, compressing the air above it right into the air canister.
3. Air canister is carefully sealed and removed from the apparatus.

The air canisters can then be used for refrigeration, as placing them inside an insulated chamber (the "fridge" with food in it) and releasing the gas outside will significantly reduce temperatures. Repeated with enough canisters, I believe the internal temperature of the "fridge" can reach below 0 degrees Celsius temperatures?

Can some kind soul explain to me the efficiency and possible limitations of this apparatus?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a ['Novel Idea' question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/1832). Such questions tend to become moving targets and lead to discussions, neither of which are a good fit for our format. See if you can [edit] your question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: I see two questions in there - 1) on the posibility of compressing air via a piston with steam acting on it (yes), 2) on the viability of cooling things with this compressed air. Total COP of such a system will be determined by both, but I think 2) is more interesting and you should focus your question on this at first.

Comment: also, FWIW, this novel idea should not be compared to large scale high tech solutions but to relativly simple devices like this zeolith solar cooling thingy.

Answer (score 1):

According to [New Atlas](https://newatlas.com/worlds-largest-solar-power-tower-plant-now-on-line/11590/), a solar power plant went online in 2009. The principles are similar to your diagram, but simpler. Mirrors (not lenses) redirect sunlight to a single point atop a tower, which converts water to high pressure steam. The steam is used to spin turbine generators, located on-site. The expended steam is thereby cooled and condensed and used again, conserving resources.

[image: solar tower]

Your design has a few economic shortcomings. The compression and expansion of air is not a particularly efficient means of refrigeration. According to a post to [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Could-compressed-air-be-used-for-heating-and-cooling):

> Compressed air is compressed because energy was expended compressing
> it, and some of that energy is stored as higher pressure. That energy
> can be used to heat or cool a number of ways, spin an electrical
> generator or refrigeration compressor upon release to a lower
> pressure, or let it expand and cool and use it as a heat sink through
> a heat exchanger, however all of those processes would be
> significantly less efficient than other solutions. And humans are
> pretty picky regarding the temperatures, humidity and pressures that
> we consider "comfortable", a narrow range of each, and compressed air
> doesn't have the properties to be used directly to create and maintain
> those conditions, and it's the intermediate steps required that
> introduce the inefficiencies.

There are a number of other posts in the same location. Losses during transport, both in energy costs of transport and also in energy loss of the "chamber" means a far-too-inefficient method of energy transfer. The issue of time as a factor in this design is not addressed in the above noted posts, but time versus thermal transfer, specifically to the surrounding environment makes the system even less efficient.

You will also have water loss in the expansion chamber, or energy loss, as the steam has to either condense to allow the piston to retract, or the water must be exhausted for the same reason.

An ordinary air compressor using an electric motor compresses air into a chamber. After the maximum safe pressure is reached, the air, containing ambient humidity can be released. The air being released is cooler than ambient, but the heat generated during compression is greater than the cooling available from the release of the pressure. A portion of this heat is from the electric motor, of course, but the net result is negative. In the solar compressor diagram, solar heat (free, more or less) has to be removed from the steam and compressed air atop the system.

Answer (score 0):

Siemens and many others have already commercially developed solar steam turbines for scalable applications. These systems supply electricity to a single household or an entire city.

See the [image: diagram]